# El Capitan - how do you enable split view? Green button only maximizes

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

Per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948, Apple suggests that holding down this green button should enable you to enter split view mode. However, nothing happens for me. If I release the green button, it enters full screen mode. I have El Capitan 11.10.5. Note, I may possibly have "custom" OSX settings that have affected this (BetterTouchTool, Karabiner, etc...). I do see the green button with two arrows, as opposed to "+", suggesting that the app "Chrome", supports split view.

Comment: Figured it out. I had set "displays have separate spaces" in preferences as suggested in link above, but didn't realize I had to log out or reboot. Now it works.

Comment: I suggest you post that as an answer to help future users who might have your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had set "displays have separate spaces" in preferences as suggested in link above, but didn't realize I had to log out or reboot. Now it works.